# array dublicate rotated individually along curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

How can I make an array follow a curve AND control a tilt or rotation of the individual duplicates along the curve? I've tried out including a lattice modifier in the stack but controlling it precisely appears a bit of a struggle.

Any ideas of how to do?

[image: array dublicate rotated along curve]

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that (other than by tilting a subdivided curve but it's a bit tedious). In Right Click Select, an Edit modifier has been asked, it would allow to treat each instance as an independent object

Comment: Thanks:) Yet, Sorry: I cannot visualize "Right Click Select, Edit modifier has been asked". Can you please explain what it means. Which command is it? Can I find it via F3-shortkey? Kind regards, Raaskot

Comment: Right Click Select is a website where you can suggest some improvements for Blender: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: Ah, I see:) 
Thank you. Ill go on with a request. Kind regards, Mikael

Comment: I think your request is this one: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/F8gbbc/